# Benefits and Drawbacks of Unsubscribing from Firebase listeners with respect to billing and data usage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm working on developing an app for my business, and I'm using Vuejs with Vuex and firebase firestore as my backend. This is my first larger scale application where I'm managing so many things, and I'm having some trouble finding some best practices regarding when and why to unsubscribe to listeners due to the complexities of how the caching layer works with firebase.

To my understanding, when you subscribe to a document or collection(we'll use collection moving forward) the entire collection will be pulled into local cache, and be made available. This speeds up query's, and other data access features. More importantly, when changes occur, the DELTAS are the only things that are actually transferred, and the only things you are billed for. In other words, if you have 1000 documents in a collection, and you subscribe, initially you will make 1000 reads, then if a document changes, you'll be at a net 1001 reads. 5 more document changes and that listener will be at 1006.

Where I'm struggling is this. Say I have a page that needs access to those 1000 documents. When I navigate away from it, it seems from what people state, that I should unsubscribe. However, when the user returns to that page, maybe a few moments or minutes later, I would resubscribe to that collection, and start listening again. Will this pull the entire collection of 1000 documents on initial subscription again? If there may only be 10-15 changes in the time before a user returns (which is reasonable with respects to my use case), then would it not be substantially more beneficial to simply leave the stream open even though the data changes don't need to be monitored for my user?

I understand that each application is different and if you have 1000 users updating those documents regularly, it would obviously be cheaper to unsubscribe every time. But for my case, maybe 30 users, and many thousands of documents: inventory transactions, material and work order transactions, etc. It seems like unsubscribing is a bad idea.

Tl;dr

I guess more directly my question is, does the caching layer persist for specific collections if you unsubscribe and re-subscribe? Or does it retransfer the entire collection in to a newly created caching instance for the new stream and manage it from there. Does this work the way I'm describing or have I massively missed something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this [part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) is interesting for you:

> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.

I like to use something I call "provider listeners". As you mentioned I was not happy about the solution that each time you leave a list it would recall the whole list. And I used the `RTD` (there was no Firestore). That solution seems to me so good that I stick with it also now with `Firestore`.

A provider listener does exactly what you explained. It listens to a list and stays with it even if you leave the list UI. I have made some API so I can unsubscribe if the user goes to a completely different part of the app. But if he just enters an entry of the list and goes back the list listener will persist. I say list because the same concept works with `RTDB` and `Firestore`. I don't know if there is something similar in VueJS. I made those solution on my own using the react providers.

The reason no one can tell you exactly if you are billed for `re-listening` a collection is that it depends on multiple things like the time explained at the start and even space on your device, indexing etc..

If the use case fits in this schema: large list, mid size amount of changes in the list I would recommend to try it witch such a concept of provider listeners. And in the end even if the collection would be cached you would be billed for the same changes for both solutions with the potential extra billing for the whole list if you unsubscribe.

Just for example this [project](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted) uses those provider listeners.

Comment: reading through that section more closely, it looks like it does indeed cache locally for 30 minutes? after that the local cache would be invalidated and the entire query will be returned/billed? I wish this was a bit more clearly defined as it has quite a large impact on architecture.

Comment: I'd love some more info on the inner-workings of your "provider listeners" design. Are you storing the listeners in global state and leaving them active within a large portion of the app, but when you go to another--completely unrelated--section of the app you trigger the unsub? Or do you have another strategy for managing this?

Comment: I save the data to the `localStorage` for offline usage and always read from there. The listeners are all abow the whole app. That way I can subscribe and unsbscribe them in any part of the app. In most cases I leave them and use unsub only for large lists and specific scenarios (sometimes there is so much data that i blows up the localStorage of the browser). The providers are abowe the routing. That is the main point.

Comment: Its an interesting idea. So you're effectively managing the "cache layer" manually. Its a bummer these things aren't small changes you can A/B test them for billing/data usage purposes. Thank you! I'll be curious if anyone else has other solutions.

Comment: You don't need to store it there like I do. It is just to unify how my app works. All state is saved to the same place not just firebase data. I don't diable the cache from firebase. It handles the cache on it's own and if it saves reads with it my cache would not interfer it.